# update dict value from one to another based on condition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

Is there any better way to write following code? I have two dict with same set of data as key, I want to iterate dict_a and check if any key with only one value, then update the value to dict_b. I have following working code but it seem there should be a better way to do it

```
dict_a = {
'first': {1,2},
'second': {2, 7, 10, 22},
'third': {3},
'fourth': {6,8},
'fifth': {1},
}
dict_b = {
'first': 11,
'second': 4,
'third': 1,
'fourth': 1000,
'fifth': 8
}
for k, v in dict_a.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        dict_b[k] = v.pop()
#=>  
#dict_b = {
#'first': 11,
#'second': 4,
#'third': 3,
#'fourth': 1000,
#'fifth': 1
#}
```

Comment: This will modify the values in `dict_a` as well. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, i do not really care about dict_a actually

Answer (score 3):

You can make it a one-liner using [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) and a generator:

```
dict_b.update((k, v.pop()) for k, v in dict_a.items() if len(v) == 1)
```

Algorithmically, this doesn't gain anything, but will utilize some optimzations that come with the used syntactic means.

Answer (score 2):

You are, possibly unnecessarily, modifying `dict_a` when you use `pop` on `set` values in `dict_a`. You can, instead, use `next` + `iter` to extract the only value of a `set`:

```
dict_b[k] = next(iter(v))
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to result in what the OP wants, but rather pulls the first element from each set. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think so.. if the length of a set is 1, i.e. the unchanged `if` clause, then pulling the only (as it happens, "first") element from each set is exactly what `v.pop` achieves.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to put this within the existing conditional. My mistake. Clever implementation.

Comment: @JonahBishop Also, sets are inherently unordered. First and last have no meaning. Both methods retrieve *any* element.